# Structuring dataframe for full model ANOVA

Tags: r, anova

I want to test the significance of the main effects, the two-way interactions, and the three-way interactions of the following dataframe - specifically,

Main effects = Self-Monitors (High vs. Low), Argument (Strong vs. Weak), Source (Attractive vs. Expert)

Two-way interactions = Self-Monitors*Argument, Self-Monitors*Source, Argument*Source

Three-way interactions = Self-Monitors*Argument*Source

This is the code:

```
data<-data.frame(Monitor=c(rep("High.Self.Monitors", 24),rep("Low.Self.Monitors", 24)),
                 Argument=c(rep("Strong", 12), rep("Weak", 12), rep("Strong", 12), rep("Weak", 12)),
                 Expert.Source=c(4,3,4,5,2,5,4,6,3,4,5,4,3,5,3,2,6,4,4,3,5,3,2,3,3,5,5,4,3,2,1,5,3,4,3,4,5,6,4,7,6,7,5,6,4,6,7,5),
             Attractive.Source=c(4,4,2,3,5,3,2,3,4,3,2,4,5,5,7,5,6,4,3,5,6,7,7,6,5,4,3,2,4,6,2,4,4,3,4,3,6,4,4,2,4,5,4,3,4,2,3,4))
data$Monitor<-as.factor(data$Monitor)
data$Argument<-as.factor(data$Argument)
```

I can do two-way interactions and the main effects, but I can't do the three-way interaction, as seen below:

```
anova(lm(Expert.Source ~ Monitor+Argument+Monitor*Argument, data))
anova(lm(Attractive.Source ~ Monitor+Argument+Monitor*Argument, data))
```

I surmise that this could be solved with a simple structuring of the dataframe, or with an R package that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what error you were getting. I've attached the code I used and the results I got. I was able to use a three way interaction. This is a lot harder with larger data FYI. Some additional info / errors would help us get you to the answer.

```
data<-data.frame(Monitor=c(rep("High.Self.Monitors", 24),rep("Low.Self.Monitors", 24)),
             Argument=c(rep("Strong", 12), rep("Weak", 12), rep("Strong", 12), rep("Weak", 12)),
             Expert.Source=c(4,3,4,5,2,5,4,6,3,4,5,4,3,5,3,2,6,4,4,3,5,3,2,3,3,5,5,4,3,2,1,5,3,4,3,4,5,6,4,7,6,7,5,6,4,6,7,5),
             Attractive.Source=c(4,4,2,3,5,3,2,3,4,3,2,4,5,5,7,5,6,4,3,5,6,7,7,6,5,4,3,2,4,6,2,4,4,3,4,3,6,4,4,2,4,5,4,3,4,2,3,4))

data$Monitor<-as.factor(data$Monitor)
data$Argument<-as.factor(data$Argument)

anova(lm(Expert.Source ~ Monitor+Argument+Monitor*Argument, data))
anova(lm(Attractive.Source ~ Monitor+Argument+Monitor*Argument*Expert.Source, data))




                  Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
Monitor                         1  5.333  5.3333  4.3392
Argument                        1 16.333 16.3333 13.2888
Expert.Source                   1 15.227 15.2269 12.3886
Monitor:Argument                1  4.152  4.1516  3.3778
Monitor:Expert.Source           1  0.230  0.2301  0.1872
Argument:Expert.Source          1  0.023  0.0234  0.0191
Monitor:Argument:Expert.Source  1  1.454  1.4538  1.1828
Residuals                      40 49.164  1.2291
```